# Is a Number Divisible by 40

Tags: divisibility

One of the "shortcuts" for determining if a number is divisible by `8` is to see if the last three digits are divisible by `8`. One of the "shortcuts" for determining if a number is divisible by `5` is to see whether the last digit is a `5` or a `0`. If I have a number of arbitrary length, is it acceptable to say that the number is divisible by `40` if the number passes both shortcuts?

Comment: Yes. Since $\gcd(8, 5)=1$, then if $8|k$ and $5|k$, it follows that $40|k$.

Comment: Actually the gcd is only needed if you want to state a sufficient condition. If $a$ and $b$ divide $n$, then $ab$ divides $n$.

Comment: @Henrik, this is not always true, unless I am understanding you wrong. Both 6 and 2 divide 18, however 2*6=12 does not divide 18.

Comment: But if `6` and `2` were coprime (I realize they are not), then Henrick's statement would be correct?

Comment: "..last three **digits**..", not "numbers".

Comment: @mathh Point taken; edited.

Comment: The logical implication $a\mid n, b\mid n\implies ab\mid n$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$ if and only if $(a,b)=1$. If $(a,b)\neq 1$, then this implication does not necessarily hold and $\exists n\in\mathbb N(a\mid n \wedge b\mid n\wedge ab\not\mid n)$.

Comment: @Dasherman: Right, but $\gcd = 1$ still isn't necessary ($2$ and $4$ both divide $24$ and so does their product, even though their $\gcd $ is $2$).

Comment: @Henrik: You are right. I think I misunderstood your original comment. gcd(a, b)=1 is indeed a sufficient, but not a neccesary condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since $8$ and $5$ are coprime $(\gcd(8, 5)=1)$. This means that such an integer can be written as $8\times 5\times n=40\times n$, for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 0):

To offer some clarity towards Henrik's point:

It is true that if a|n and b|n then if gcd(a,b)=1 then (ab)|n.

However, we may generalize somewhat, and note that lcm(a,b) = (ab)/gcd(a,b) will always divide n, provided that both a|n and b|n

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Any number whose last $3$ digits are a multiple of $40$ are a multiple of $40$. It also works if the $100$s digit is even and the last $2$ digits are $00$, $40$ or $80$, or if the $100$s digit is odd and the last $2$ digits are $20$ or $60$.